Outdoor Farm Yard Pole Lamp Intermittently on

Barn yard light on a pole is going off and on. Supposed to be on in the evening and off in the day but this is not always the case when it's raining or windy. There's a switch inside that turns it off and on but haven't found the breaker yet. It likely in the neighbors house but the light has been off for so long recently haven't had the chance to check for sure.
The pole doesn't have meter or transformer attached to it from a power company.
What is going on with the wiring, particularly the braided wire? I've never seen a gauge like that or exposed. Is it just the ground?
Assuming all the splices need to be housed in a junction box but at the very least a waterproof nut and one significantly larger.
Landlord hasn't sent any help. Won't attempt anything I'm not comfortable with, or fully understand.


Landlord hasn't sent any help.

In most areas that means you must have a licensed electrician do all work.
That being said, a few comments:

That looks really bad.
I wouldn't do anything to that without first finding the breaker, turning it off and verifying that all wires in the vicinity are truly dead.
The connections should be in a box.
Individual wires, as opposed to cables, should not be exposed.
Any wires and cables involved need to be rated for outdoor (= wet) use.

Turning off a breaker is not electrical work. So actually, if you can find and turn off the breaker that would be a Really Good Idea ™ for safety. And if it turns out that the same breaker/circuit runs your neighbor's internet connection then I'll bet they'll get the landlord out there in a hurry. On the other hand, if it only runs this pole and a few other lights somewhere then it won't help get the landlord out but it will make you safer. In particular, exposed wires can be easily chewed through by critters. Sometimes that results in fried critters. But it can also result in an exposed but still live bare hot conductor, which can be dangerous in terms of both life safety and fire safety.
